# What is "net assets for common stock"?

Tags: stocks

I've looked online and could only find this definition:

> Net Assets for Common Stock Holders = All Assets Less All Liabilities Less Apportioned Value for Preferred and Minority Shareholders.

So it must be a percentage of the (Assets - Liabilities), the percentage that is not allocated to preferred stock or to stock that's not publicly traded.

But I'm trying to make sense of it in a practical sense, so I went to see some reports. That's what's not making sense right now.

**How am I supposed to get from 377,404 to 352,417?** (Table 1, March column, lines 1 and 2)

[image]

This is a screenshot from this report here: https://www.sojitz.com/jp/ir/financial%5Cupload%5C2011_02_all_d.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below explains the difference - minority interests. Minority interests is the amount of a subsidiary that is not owned by the parent company, which means that some of the value of the subsidiary does not belong to the parent company's shareholders.

It would have been clearer if the minority interests had been listed before the next assets available to common stockholders so that it would indicate that the total was the net assets *minus* the minority interests.